# How can I find a $n$-th degree polynomial for a line with $n-1$ predetermined points?

Tags: polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

Essentially, I have a set of points which I want to create a polynomial that passes through a set of points. This is within the context of having set locations on a line to set times. It is preferred that the time be between 0 and 1 at all times. For example, when I have 5 target points, the times would be x = $0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: If you have $n+1$ points, there is a unique $n$-th degree polynomial which passes through all of those points (which can be found using Lagrange's method).  If you have $n-1$ points and want to construct an $n$-th degree polynomial, you have a little bit of freedom to move things around (you'll have two free parameters which you can choose freely).

Comment: A quick search on google would have given you the answer

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace If you have nothing positive to contribute, why leave a comment?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Relevant is not necessarily positive. One should post a question only if one has verified that there is no easy access reference that answers it. By easy I mean Google search. For a new contributor it is important to remark it, although I'll admit I was rude.

Comment: nah you're right, in hindsight i probably shouldn't have posted this since its really simple